# How to adjust col to row?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid-system

I have a grid system in a page where I want a row to have 2 cols inside of it.
The cols are bigger than the row.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bd1q36rw/)**

Example: If the row has 20px of height, so do the cols.

I want the cols to adjust to the row, not act independent.

```
<!--HTML-->
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-8">
              dhfjk
              <br>fudff
              <br>udfhjdkl
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

```css
/*CSS*/
.col-4{
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 0%;
}

.col-4{
    border: 3px red solid;
}

.col-8{
    border: 3px blue solid;
}

.container-fluid{
    padding: 50px;
}

.row{
    border: 5px solid green;
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you have a `max-height` on the row?

Comment: I just solved it please check !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe that can help you

```
.col-4 {
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 0%;
    max-height: -webkit-fill-available;
     border: 3px red solid;
}

.col-8{
    border: 3px blue solid;
    max-height: -webkit-fill-available;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.container-fluid{
    padding: 50px;
}

.row {
    border: 5px solid green;
    max-height: 50px;
}

.row:nth-of-type(2){
   max-height: -webkit-fill-available;
    overflow: scroll
}

img{
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given `max-height:50` to row, remove that cols will be equal to row !

```css
/*CSS*/
.col-4{
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 0%;
}

.col-4{
    border: 3px red solid;
}

.col-8{
    border: 3px blue solid;
}

.container-fluid{
    padding: 50px;
}

.row{
    border: 5px solid green;
    
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-8">
              dhfjk
              <br>fudff
              <br>udfhjdkl
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've made the row adjust to the col, not the other way. I need the col to adjust to the size of the row..

Comment: its the image you are using that is taking height, if you remove image it will be inside row or you want to add content still wants height to be same then i think you have to `scroll` content
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just use this css

```
/*CSS*/
.col-4{
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 0%;
}

.col-4{
    border: 3px red solid;
     padding: 7px;
}

.col-8{
    border: 3px blue solid;
}

.container-fluid{
    padding: 50px;
}

.row{
    border: 5px solid green;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```